# ASP.NET Connection String Error

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

I used this connection to run my SQL query, but it did not work and sent this error:

`Keyword not supported: 'dsn'`

This is my connection:

```
public static string CnnStr = @"Dsn=Server;uid=kity;app=Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010;wsid=kity;database=Server;trusted_connection=Yes";
```

This connection works for me in my datalist, but for my behind code it gives me this error.  II should say that I used ODBC connection to database.

Comment: could you provide us the text that Exception throws

Comment: Which database product you are using?

Answer (score 0):

create `any` **.udl** file

press enter on it

detect your data source and copy and paste you Connection String in the asp.net code

Comment: I do this and this connection string is the exact that copy of string but i dont know why it does not work,it works when i use in sqldatasource but when i use it as a code in code behind it shows me that error

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a value for `providerName=System.Data.Odbc` into the connection string.

Like this:

```
@"Dsn=Server;uid=kity;app=Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010;wsid=kity;database=Server;trusted_connection=Yes;providerName=System.Data.Odbc;"
```

If that doesn't work, take a look at the same question in different situations:

[Keyword not supported exception when attempting to use a connection string that points to a ODBC DSN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567037/keyword-not-supported-exception-when-attempting-to-use-a-connection-string-that)

[Keyword not supported: 'dsn'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640146/keyword-not-supported-dsn)

Note: the "Keyword not supported: ..." error usually comes from an incorrectly formatted connection string.

Comment: I try providerName=System.Data.Odbc but It doesn't work too and gives me same error